# Receive images via Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am able to transfer data (a string) over Bluetooth but I'm stuck with image transfer.
I want to receive images from a PC app via Bluetooth, store them, and fetch them in my Android app when needed.

Is files useful for the purpose?
Any help appreciated.
Any reference code if available please do share.

Answer (score 0):

If you are connected with a peer, you can obtain BluetoothSocket object. It gives you a  OutputStream and you can write whatever you want. Since android 3.0 you can build own bluetooth profile or use predefined. Unfortunately it doesn't support any image pushes (BIP, OPP, etc.), so you have to implement it ( probbaly API which you use on PC side has it ). You can always build raw binary protocol.